# Moving listview up and down by buttons

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am trying to use 2 buttons (up and down) to move up and down in the listview highlighting each item depending on what direction its going in the listview.

This is my current code:

```
Private Sub cmdDown_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdDown.Click
    If cmdDown.Tag <> totalRecordsReturned Then
        cmdDown.Tag += 1
        ListView1.Items(cmdDown.Tag).Selected = True
        ListView1.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

That does work **But** it selects more items every time i hit the button. What can i do in order to correct this?

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Design View, select Multiselect = False

or add this one line in your code

```
ListView1.MultiSelect = False
```

like this

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ListView1.MultiSelect = False
End Sub

Private Sub cmdDown_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles cmdDown.Click
    If cmdDown.Tag <> totalRecordsReturned Then
        cmdDown.Tag += 1
        ListView1.Items(cmdDown.Tag).Selected = True
        ListView1.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: No reason to execute the code each time the `cmdDown_Click` function executes. Set it in the form's constructor.

Comment: Edited the above post as per Cody's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use this solution. using listview keyup/keydown :

```
Private Sub lvSearch_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles lvSearch.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then

            If lvSearch.SelectedItems(0).Index < (lvSearch.Items.Count - 1) Then

                txtName.Text = lvSearch.Items(lvSearch.SelectedItems(0).Index + 1).SubItems(1).Text

            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub lvSearch_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles lvSearch.KeyUp
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
            If lvSearch.SelectedItems(0).Index >= 0 Then

                txtName.Text = lvSearch.Items(lvSearch.SelectedItems(0).Index).SubItems(1).Text

            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This was very helpful and I used it for my project but it's a little different. I have a listview where the first column is a fixed index so the user knows how many items are in the list and can refer to them by number. This is a problem when moving the items up and down as the index number in column 1 needs to stay the same and only change the data in column 2. I wrote the class below which also supports add,delete and renaming of column 2 items.

```
Public Class class_ListViewControl

Public ListViewControl_DebugMode As Boolean = True ' to show exceptions in debug mode 


Public Sub Init_ListView(ByRef SelectedListView As ListView, ByVal FullRowSelect As Boolean, ByVal ViewMode As View, ByVal Columns() As String)

    ' Pass the list to modify, two common settings and an array of columns by string name 
    Try

        SelectedListView.View = ViewMode
        SelectedListView.FullRowSelect = FullRowSelect

        SelectedListView.Columns.Clear()

        For i As Integer = 0 To Columns.Length - 1
            SelectedListView.Columns.Add(Columns(i), -2)
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        If ListViewControl_DebugMode = True Then MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try


End Sub

Public Sub MoveListViewItem(ByRef SelectedlistView As ListView, ByVal move As ArrowDirection)

    ' Pass the listview to edit and the command UP/DOWN 

    Try
        ' Select between UP/DOWN arrows 
        If move = ArrowDirection.Up And SelectedlistView.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then

            Dim selected As ListViewItem = SelectedlistView.SelectedItems(0)
            Dim indx As Integer = selected.Index
            Dim totl As Integer = SelectedlistView.Items.Count

            If indx > 0 Then ' Make sure it's not 0 

                Dim temp As String = SelectedlistView.Items(indx - 1).SubItems(1).Text ' save the string from the old one first so we can put it in the new location 

                ' move the text in column 2 to the column 2 index below it and place the old text in the next column
                SelectedlistView.Items(indx - 1).SubItems(1).Text = SelectedlistView.Items(indx).SubItems(1).Text
                SelectedlistView.Items(indx).SubItems(1).Text = temp

                ' This clears the selection then selects the new index before existing. This allows the user to hit UP again with out having to reselect the item 
                SelectedlistView.SelectedItems.Clear()
                SelectedlistView.Items(indx - 1).Selected = True

            End If


        ElseIf move = ArrowDirection.Down And SelectedlistView.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then


            Dim selected As ListViewItem = SelectedlistView.SelectedItems(0)
            Dim indx As Integer = selected.Index
            Dim totl As Integer = SelectedlistView.Items.Count

            If indx < SelectedlistView.Items.Count - 1 Then ' if it's less than the max index you can just move the data to the next one 

                Dim temp As String = SelectedlistView.Items(indx + 1).SubItems(1).Text

                SelectedlistView.Items(indx + 1).SubItems(1).Text = SelectedlistView.Items(indx).SubItems(1).Text
                SelectedlistView.Items(indx).SubItems(1).Text = temp

                ' This clears the selection then selects the new index before existing. This allows the user to hit DOWN again with out having to reselect the item 
                SelectedlistView.SelectedItems.Clear()
                SelectedlistView.Items(indx + 1).Selected = True


            End If

            End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        If ListViewControl_DebugMode = True Then MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try



End Sub

Public Sub EditListViewItem(ByRef SelectedListView As ListView, ByVal EditType As Char, ByVal NewText As String)

    ' Pass the listview to edit, EditType: ADD = 'A' DELETE = 'D', and Index of item 
    Try

        Dim selected As ListViewItem = Nothing
        Dim indx As Integer = 0

        If SelectedListView.SelectedIndices.Count > 0 Then ' Only load if something is selected 
            selected = SelectedListView.SelectedItems(0)
            indx = selected.Index
        Else
            ' This is here because you don't need an index selected to add a new item. 
            selected = Nothing
            indx = 0 ' set to 0
        End If



        Dim total As Integer = SelectedListView.Items.Count

        Select Case EditType

            Case "A" ' ADD NEW 

                Dim NewItem As New ListViewItem(CStr(total + 1))

                NewItem.SubItems.Add(NewText)
                SelectedListView.Items.Add(NewItem)

            Case "D" ' DELETE 
                If selected IsNot Nothing Then ' only execute if something is selected 

                    SelectedListView.Items.Remove(selected) ' Delete the selected item 

                    For i As Integer = 0 To SelectedListView.Items.Count - 1
                        SelectedListView.Items(i).SubItems(0).Text = CStr(i + 1)
                    Next


                End If

            Case "S" ' Save edits 

                SelectedListView.Items(indx).SubItems(1).Text = NewText

        End Select

    Catch ex As Exception
        If ListViewControl_DebugMode = True Then MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try


End Sub
```

End Class

To use this class, on your form 1 declarations add:

```
 Private ListViewClass As New class_ListViewControl
```

Then in the Form_Load sub add your initialization:

```
  ListViewClass.Init_ListView(lstv_RFPInfo_Options, True, View.Details, {"#", "Option Title"})
```

Add button Example:

```
ListViewClass.EditListViewItem(listview1, "A", textbox1.Text)
```

Delete button Example:

```
ListViewClass.EditListViewItem(listview1, "D", "")
```

[Form 1 example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7wNR.jpg)